# Python character length of a binary value

Tags: python, math, binary

I am looking for way to determine the number of characters my binary value takes up.

For example if my values binary values were 4, 20, and 60 I'd get the following results:

```
bin(4), 0b100 = 3

bin(20), 0b10100 = 5

bin(60), 0b111100 = 6
```

Comment: Also, in recent versions, `x.bit_length()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive integer *n* has *b* bits when 2<sup>b-1</sup> ≤ n ≤ 2<sup>b</sup> – 1. So The number of bits required to represent an integer *n* is :

```
floor(log n)+1 # note that base of log is 2
```

And since you have `0b` at the leading you need to add 2 to aforementioned formula.

So it would be :

```
floor(log n) + 3
```

And in python you can use `math` module like following:

```
math.floor(math.log(n, 2)) + 3
```

Example :

```
>>> math.floor(math.log(10, 2)) + 3
6.0
>>> 
>>> len(bin(10))
6
>>> math.floor(math.log(77, 2)) + 3
9.0
>>> len(bin(77))
9
```

As a more **Pythonic** way you can also use [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) which returns the number of bits needs to represent an integer object. So for get the number of require characters you can add it with 2 :

```
int.bit_length() + 2
```

Comment: Using `floor(log(n, 2)) + 1` isn't a good idea if you need correct results for larger inputs. For example, it gives the wrong result on my machine for `562949953421311` (the correct answer is `49`, but on my machine this formula gives `50`). In recent Python versions, you can use `log2`, which is a bit more accurate than `log(n, 2)`, but there's really no point when the `bit_length` method is available.

Comment: @MarkDickinsonThanks for edit. Yep that's because of the restricts in calculating the floating point numbers. But at first I thought OP is looking fora mathematical approach and actually I've missed `bit_length` function.

Comment: `bit_length` is a method and should be called

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 20
a.bit_length()
>> 5
```